# I tried to connect my Android app to google firebase but it displays an error

Tags: android, database, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I tried to connect my app to google firebase, I followed the procedure with implementation in Gradle as well as JSON file. After that, I tried to run my app and it displayed this error message:

[image]

This is my Gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
    }


    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
```

This is my other Gradle module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ius"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

If you could help me that would mean the world to me. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow don't post error messages as images but do paste them in the question in text format only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `minSdkVersion 15` to `minSdkVersion 16`

As the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) stated that

> Make sure that your app meets the following requirements:
>   **Targets API level 16 (Jelly Bean) or later**

Comment: How do I changed it? Can you guide me please

Comment: In your Gradle module file change this `minSdkVersion 15` to `minSdkVersion 16`
[Image Link](https://imgur.com/a/Re8RCS0)

Comment: Thank you soo much, you saved me <333

Comment: @user738462 I'm glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Some of your library has minSdk 16. So you must change your minSdkVersion to 16 or change library that compatibility with sdk 15.

In your build.gradle(Module leve)

change 
    `minSdkVersion 15`
to `minSdkVersion 16` in `defaultConfig`

PS. Why you use minSDk is 16, I think use 21 still fine.

Comment: How do I changed it? Can you guide me please

Comment: Please check my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

In defaultConfig change of minSdkVersion from 15 to 16 may do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

> decrease version library

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

Comment: remove all firebase dependency and add firebase by selecting Assistent in Android studio